# Where is DoubleUpperTriMatrix structure type located?

Tags: data-structures, vb.net-2010

I need to create a DoubleUpperTriMatrix data structure in my app but I can't find where it is located so I can import the needed libraries. Using Google found that people include it via `System.Object.CenterSpace.NMath.Matrix.DoubleUpperTriMatrix` but it seems on Visual Studio 2010 it is not there anymore. How do I include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This component](http://www.centerspace.net/doc/NMathSuite/ref/html/T_CenterSpace_NMath_Matrix_DoubleUpperTriMatrix.htm) is not a part of Visual Studio, nor is it published by Microsoft. It is published by a 3rd-party called [CenterSpace Software](http://www.centerspace.net/) as part of their [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) package, which you will need to purchase.